# kml document auto refresh in google earth

Tags: kml, google-earth

I have an app that over time writes `Placemarks` to a `kml` file, slowly building up a route over time.

When I open the file in Google Earth, I can see the `Placemarks` already in the file, but any new ones added to the doc aren't shown on the map, until I reopen the document again.

Is there any way of getting the document to auto refresh in Google earth?

I've tried putting a `NetworkLink` into the document whose href points itself (the file) with a `refreshMode` of `onChange`, and that works, but the whole document is reloaded on each change and each point is displayed again, which is messy.

NOTE: I can't change the apps code, to generate single `Placemark` updates, which I believe is the proper way of using `NetworkLinks`.

Comment: I guess you will have to modify the library (if you are using any). KMLs are processed in entirity. You may write your own logic to read the kml and add path between last drawn point to the newly added point. I guess I have understood your problem correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to perform incremental updates in KML is using the [NetworkLinkControl](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#networklinkcontrol) element in conjunction with a [NetworkLink](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#networklink).

NetworkLinkControl controls the behavior of files fetched by a `<NetworkLink>` in which you can change, add, or delete elements that you already fetched.

```
 <NetworkLinkControl>
    <cookie>cookie=sometext</cookie>
    <linkName>link name</linkName>
    <Update>
      <targetHref>same-targethref-for-networklink</targetHref>
      <Create>
        <Document targetId="targetdoc">
          <Placemark>
            <name>Created place1</name>
          </Placemark>
          <Placemark>
            <name>Created place2</name>
          </Placemark>
        </Document>
      </Create>
      ...
    </Update>
 </NetworkLinkControl>
```

The NetworkLinkControl is tricky to get working such as the URLs in the NetworkLink and NetworkLinkControl must match exactly.

You can find a tutorial with an example to get started.
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/updates

Answer (score 0):

So I guess you can't. I thought there might be some kind of structure within kml to achieve this, nut it would appear not.